# Get records "Jone Deo" or "Deo Jone" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can we get the result of "Jone Deo" or "Deo Jone" in mysql?
Example.

**Table Name students**

ID------Name

1-------Jone Deo

2-------Bill Gates

Now, if someone enter **Deo Jone** or **Jone Deo** then **Jone Deo** records will be search out in mysql

I've search box in my website. If someone search "Jone Deo" or "Deo Jone", I will need only result from above tables.
I don't want to use PHP loop or explode function.

Comment: any sample or attempted code?

Comment: @Jah Actually, I want only mysql query. I searched a lot but I did not get any results. Hence, I posted questions here. :)

Comment: Entered how? Are you trying to query this database with any combination of strings delimited with a space? Any other logic you want to apply?

Comment: @tshimkus, I just edited my questions. I 've search box in my website. If someone search "Jone Deo" or "Deo Jone", I will need only result from above tables. I don't want to use PHP loop or explode function. for get this results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try Full-text search:

```
 SELECT * FROM People WHERE MATCH (full_name)
    AGAINST ('+Doe +John' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d21d4e/5

Full-text search explained: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

"Full-text searching is performed using MATCH() ... AGAINST syntax. MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched. AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row."

So in short, to answer your question you should see an improvement in query execution times by implementing a full text index on wide VARCHAR columns. Providing you are using a compatible storage engine ( InnoDB or MyISAM)

Comment: Will Full Text search slow our search process ?

Comment: It is working in my case. Thank you so much for your wonderful help. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Jone[[:>:]]' AND REGEXP '[[:<:]]Deo[[:>:]]';
```

This would also handle the case where you just wanted to assert that `Jone` and `Deo` appear as standalone words anywhere in the name, even if the name had e.g. a middle component.

Comment: But how can I split the words ? 
Is this possible without PHP's explod or loop ?

Comment: What do you mean by "split the words?"

Comment: In search box, users will enter "John Deo" together. As per you solution need to explode/split the whole word into 2 words.

Comment: Use PHP's `split` function?  It is up to you how you separate the terms entered.  My answer (and your original question) have to do with what query you could run given those two separate terms, not how to obtain them from a PHP script.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to use split/explod or any loop of PHP. Is this possible using mysql  query?

Comment: If you are suggesting that you pass a multiword input to MySQL and then use string functions to separate it, then it's a really bad idea.  Build a prepared statement in PHP, and then run it against MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you can append % at the beginning and end of each word of the string, you can use the following query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 
name 
LIKE 
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("%Jone% %Deo%", " ", -1)) 
OR 
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("%Jone% %Deo%", " ", 1))
```

Tested and working for both Deo Jone and Jone Deo.